# Dice Buttons Won't Allow Dice to Roll in My Game?

Tags: vb.net, dice

I just made some changes to my code for this app, but for some reason it is still not working. My restart button is not restarting the form, my score numbers are not showing up, the outcome results are not showing up, the dice are not rolling.

Here is the link to my GUI: https://imageshack.com/i/kpdOTIAQp

Basically, a human player is playing against a COMPUTER using VB's built in random number generator. The objective of the game is for either opponent to have a higher score than the other to win the game in a best of an odd number of matches format from 1 up to 99 ( like 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 and so forth).

The problem is that the dice images do not show up when you click the button.

```
Public Class DiceBattleForm

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
        Dim RESPONSE As MsgBoxResult
        RESPONSE = MsgBox("Do you want to exit?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.Question)
        If RESPONSE = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Me.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RollButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RollButton.Click
        If GameTextBox.Text <= "0" Then
            MsgBox("Number of Games > 0", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            Application.Restart()
        End If

        If GameTextBox.Text > "0" Then
            GameTextBox = Convert.ToInt32(GameTextBox.Text)
        End If


        DisplayDie(PCDice1)
        DisplayDie(PCDice2)
        DisplayDie(PCDice3)

        DisplayDie(YouDice1)
        DisplayDie(YouDice2)
        DisplayDie(YouDice3)
    End Sub

    Sub DisplayDie(diePictureBox As PictureBox)
        'GENERATE random integer in range 1 to 6
        Dim face As Integer = randomObject.Next(1, 7)

        'retrieve specific die image from resources
        Dim pictureResource = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String.Format("die{0}", face))

        'Convert pictureResource to type Image and display in ImageBox
        diePictureBox.Image = CType(pictureResource, Image)
    End Sub ' DisplaDie


    Private Sub GameTextBox_Validating(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GameTextBox.TextChanged
        If GameTextBox.Text > "0" Then
            Do
                MsgBox(GameTextBox.Text + " round(s) will be played enjoy!")
            Loop While GameTextBox.Text = "STOP"
        End If
        GameTextBox.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub RestartButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RestartButton.Click
        ' Reset or clear any controls (recommended)
        DiceBattleForm.Clear()
        ' NOT recommended:
        ' Application.Restart()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Maybe it's time you start over. Sometime you get caugh up in the code and don't see any way out. I would suggest you start over and build/test the application one feature at a time. Don't try to build everything at once.

Comment: Okay, well first I know the exit button works, so that is one part I have done. The problem that I want to fix is getting the dice to roll. By looking at my code do you where my problem is that is preventing me from getting the dice to roll the_lotus?

Comment: Your original question was put on hold as being too broad. This question is no more focused. Learn from your question being put on hold and come up with a clearer question. This being said, your application looks very over complicated for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okay sorry about that. But here is one question I have (I'll try to be as specific as possible). When I click on the roll button and create the code/event for it I have these error lines underneath where it says DisplayDie. Is it because it is not declared somewhere? If so, how do I declare it?

Comment: "clarifications" in comments are fine, but they are ephemeral here on SO, so all that counts as far as answers is what is in the Question post.  I have edited it to narrow it down to match the title.  The original form with all sorts of functional elements is what makes it too broad - the *only* way to answer them is to write an entire program.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it slightly differently.  Rather than loading the dice images from resources, load them from an `imagelist` so that the index (represented by the `Random` result) is all you need to find the image.  Loading from resources by screwing together and integer and name may be the problem - we cant tell because we cant see what the die images are named in your resources.

Also, this type of problem is *ideal* to learn how to debug: set a breakpoint in `DisplayDie` and *see* why it was not working: e.g. is the `String.Format` result correct for the names of the images?

Roll Dice, display image from an `ImageList`:

```
Private Sub btnRoll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRoll.Click
    ' pbC1 etc are MY picturebox names - use yours
    DisplayDie(pbC1)
    DisplayDie(pbC2)
    DisplayDie(pbC3)

End Sub

Private Sub DisplayDie(diePictureBox As PictureBox)

    Dim face As Integer = randomObject.Next(1, 7)

    ' adjust pip count to image index by subtracting one
    diePictureBox.Image = ImageList1.Images(face - 1)

End Sub
```

The images are listed in the `ImageList` in pip order, so the only transform is to convert from pips (1-6) to index (0-5).

[image]

Comment: Okay I will try that out and I will let you guys know if it worked for me or not. While I'm working on that part of my app, what is causing me from not seeing the scores being tracked and how can I create the outcome messages such as "You Win" "PC Wins" and so forth?

Comment: that is a different question.  I cant see where your app is saving the pips for each in order to evaluate and then display a message, so also cant say why.

Comment: Okay Plutonix, right now I'm currently trying to figure out how to load images from imagelist, then I will let you know shortly how it works out. Also, if I have more questions regarding this app, do I have to create a new question instead?

Comment: add an imagelist to the form, click the arrow thing to open the "Action List" then select "Select Images"...you can move them up down etc after they are loaded to put them in order

Comment: Okay I found the imagelist control in the toolbox and I got my dice pictures selected. However when I try to drag it up into the form, it wont let me. It just stays all the in the bottom of the screen (if that makes sense to you). How can I drag it back into the form?

Comment: just double click it in the toolbox - it doesnt go on the form `per se` but sits in the form try - it is a component, not a control

Comment: Okay I think I know what your talking about then. Now, in order for me to see those for pictures on the form when I debug it, do I just use the code that you posted earlier, but except I will replace RollDie with RollButton_Click (since that is what I named it)? Also I want 3 dice photos setup for the PC and 3 dice photos setup for me the user. If you look at the link where it shows my GUI you will see what I'm talking about. So how would I go about it since I'm using imagelist instead of the resource and not dragging images into my form? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, in my code it says rand and pb are not declared. How would I declare it in order for to work? Also how would you call RollDie 3 times from the button click? Sorry I may misunderstood what you said so I may need some clarification. And do you still want me to use the code that I used previously or not? I'm referring to this below:

Comment: Private Sub RollButton_Click(sender As OBJECT, e As EventArgs) Handles RollButton.Click
        If GameTextBox.Text <= "0" Then
            MsgBox("Number of Games > 0", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            Application.Restart()
        End If

        If GameTextBox.Text > "0" Then
            GameTextBox = Convert.ToInt32(GameTextBox.Text)
        End If


        DisplayDie(PCDice1)
        DisplayDie(PCDice2)
        DisplayDie(PCDice3)

        DisplayDie(YouDice1)
        DisplayDie(YouDice2)
        DisplayDie(YouDice3)
    End Sub

Comment: Okay, please correct me if I mistaken what you said, but it is still okay if I use this code then below? Sub DisplayDie(diePictureBox As PictureBox)
        'GENERATE random integer in range 1 to 6
        Dim face As Integer = randomObject.Next(1, 7)

        'retrieve specific die image from resources
        Dim pictureResource = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String.Format("die{0}", face))

        'Convert pictureResource to type Image and display in ImageBox
        diePictureBox.Image = CType(pictureResource, Image)
    End Sub ' DisplaDie if so what changes do I make to it?

Comment: code does not format in comments - all you really have to change in  your original code once you have 6 die images in an image list is *where* you get the image from.  Rather than from resources, they are now (hopefully) in the ImageList, so: `diePictureBox.Image = ImageList1.Images(face - 1)` **Do** be sure they are in order there

Comment: This is what I have now, Dim pictureResource = diePictureBox.Image = ImageList1.Images(face - 1), however there is a blue line underneath the diePictureBox.Image = ImageList1.Images(face - 1). An error is saying Operator '=' is not defined for types, what is causing that problem and how do i fix it?

Comment: Okay, do I also get rid of 'GENERATE random integer in range 1 to 6
        Dim face As Integer = randomObject.Next(1, 7) and 'Convert pictureResource to type Image and display in ImageBox
        diePictureBox.Image = CType(pictureResource, Image)? Or do I keep those because right now I'm getting a blue line error underneath the pictureResource and the randomObject?

Comment: Okay, but the randomObject still has the blue error line underneath because it is not declared. How do I declare it?

Comment: I wrote it, but I'm not sure what is causing the problem still. Do you want me to send you a link of all my code so far so you could see what my problem is? It will be a picture of it.

Comment: I know what the problem is, I just told *you* what the problem is: *Your code doesnt show it [`randomObject`] being initialized or even declared.*

Comment: Okay, so how do I initialize or declare randomObject then? I thought I already declared/initialized it but I guess I did it wrong.

Comment: Or if not that, what should I replace randomObject with? DisplayDie, or diePictureBox or something else so I could have it declared/initalized? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

well, for the restart button, instead of `Form1.Clear()`

Try

```
TextBox1.Clear()
TextBox2.Clear()
TextBox3.Clear()
TextBox4.Clear()
```

and so on that should clear the textboxes, and as for the.  But really, I don't see what's wrong with the `Application.Restart()`

Comment: Okay, thanks AlwaysAStudent, I tried the APPLICATION.Restart() only and it seemed to work for me. Now, what is preventing me from seeing the dice roll? If you could continue helping me out still that would be great, thanks and hope to hear from you shortly.

Comment: I mean, I'd be glad to help more, but do you have a book or something to use as reference material?  I was just looking down through the comments on the other answer, and you seem to have quite a few questions.

Comment: Hey AlwaysAStudent, if you ever come back to this post again here are the instructions for my game and I will also give you a link to the current post, thanks for you helping me out with this, its been really stressing me out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27113632/visual-basic-loading-images-into-picturebox-from-imagelist?noredirect=1#comment42730143_27113632